# How to kill process and process with PID could not be terminated. Access is denied

Tags: windows, tomcat, server, localhost, command-prompt

I use windows 10 so I try to kill the port this command

```
netstat -ano | findstr :8006

taskkill /PID 3984 /F
```

but I didn't kill the process. But it comes

```
ERROR: The process with PID 3984 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.
```

Comment: Make sure you run cmd as admin first and see if that solves your problem. Also, I'm just gonna assume the PID used here just is an example since you never store the output from netstat anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Run your cmd as an administrator. It will work.

Comment: Can happen even with administrator command prompt

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Internet Information Services(IIS) Manager. Click on Sites and stop the website running on the required port.